# CSS Placing text next to image and making it mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, browser, responsive-design, cross-browser

I use this code: [My Code](https://jsfiddle.net/d8z571q2/)

```
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;"><a href="domain.tld"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/J5azqpQ.jpg" alt="This is a cool picture" width="300px" /> </a></div><div style="display:inline-block;"><div>13/11/2019</div><div><strong>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</strong></div><div><a href="*|FEEDITEM:URL|*"> Learn More</a><br></div></div><hr><div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;"><a href="domain.tld"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/HkwIsNL.jpg" alt="This is a cool picture" width="300px" /> </a></div><div style="display:inline-block;"><div>13/11/2019</div><div><strong>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</strong></div><div><a href="*|FEEDITEM:URL|*"> Learn More</a><br></div>
```

All I want to achieve is to be able to show the text next to the image like in picture 1 when you view the code from a PC / laptop / tablet. I need the text to be below the image on all mobile devices (Picture 2).
Is there a possible way to achieve this without media queries? Because some mobile phones have a width larger than 1080 pixels which is the same width with some old PCs.

I want to somehow determine that the user uses a mobile phone, so that i can implement different css if the user uses PC or mobile.

I share 2 photos in order for you to understand what I mean.
[on PC (Picture 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxYtV.jpg)
[on Mobile (Picture 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbXu6.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of [a lot of these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=text+next+to+image)

Answer (score 1):

you can use css media queries to adjust if the screen size changes.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* on PC */
@media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
  .featured-image {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .featured-image img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .description {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
  }
}
/* on Mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .featured-image {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .featured-image img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .description {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="featured-image">
    <a href="domain.tld"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/J5azqpQ.jpg" alt="This is a cool picture" /> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
      <div>13/11/2019</div>
      <div><strong>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</strong></div>
      <div><a href="*|FEEDITEM:URL|*"> Learn More</a><br></div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="item">
  <div class="featured-image">
    <a href="domain.tld"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/HkwIsNL.jpg" alt="This is a cool picture" /> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
      <div>13/11/2019</div>
      <div><strong>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</strong></div>
      <div><a href="*|FEEDITEM:URL|*"> Learn More</a><br></div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

see on : [CSS3 Media Queries - Examples](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: Unfortunately your solution is not good for what I want to achieve. I want to somehow determine that the user uses a mobile phone, so that i can implement different css if the user uses PC or mobile. I also cant use just "min-width" and "max-width" as some mobiles have bigger width than PCs

Comment: maybe you can use **javascript** `navigator.userAgent` or `window.orientation` to detect the device being used. here's an [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-detecting-a-mobile-browser/)

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this
just play around with the width of the elements on how you want it

css

```
.parent-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

html

```
<div class"parent-container>
  <img />
  <div class="text-container">
  <!-- text elements here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: 
You can add "media" attribute for the stylesheet link tags. You can define the device-width to that, like this

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 2400px)' href='css/medium.css' />

 <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 767px)' href='css/medium.css' />
```

You can also use jquery for this but i dont think its necessary to use jquery when you can do it with just html.

Comment: Hi louie and thanks for the input. Unfortunately your solution is not good for what I want to achieve.
I want to somehow determine that the user uses a mobile phone, so that i can implement different css if the user uses PC or mobile.
I also cant use just "min-width" as some mobiles have bigger width than PCs

Comment: Oh sorry about it, didnt saw the last part. Why not try to detect the document window and just use if else statement? If it fits the expected width, append a link tag with href='.css' to the head or else different or default stylesheet file

Comment: Could you please provide an example with this method louie?

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to avoid media queries, my suggestion is that you look into implementing a user agent to determine if the user is on a mobile browser or not.

Here's a script solution that you can implement directly with your favorite language (works with javascript, jquery etc):
http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/